# Precomposition and Closness of Functions in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f,g \in L^2_{\nu}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, for some Borel probability measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Is there a known (finite) upper-bound on
$$
\inf_{A \in Mat_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R})}\|f\circ A - g\|_{L^2_{\nu}}< k(\|f- g\|_{L^2_{\nu}},\|f\|_{L^2_{\nu}},\|g\|_{L^2_{\nu}}),
$$
where $Mat_{d\times d}(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of $d \times d$ matrices and $k$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and the inequality is *strict*.

Comment: Are you sure you want the infimum? Fixing $A=I$ yields that $k(x,y,z)=x$ just works for your upper bound, right?

Comment: Oh, but the inequality is strict

Comment: If you fiddle around a bit with examples where $\nu$ is a point mass, it seems like there isn't any nontrivial statement to be obtained here.

Comment: One other note is that the left side is not necessarily well-defined, since the matrix $A$ may map $\nu$-null sets to non-$\nu$-null sets (i.e. $\nu$ may not be quasi-invariant under linear transformations).  Remember that an element of $L^2_\nu$ is really an equivalence class under $\nu$-a.e. equivalence, and you may have $f_1 \sim f_2$ but $f_1 \circ A \not\sim f_2 \circ A$.

Comment: Ah true, thanks Nate.  I think indeed there is nothing to enlightening to be said by the inequality.  Thanks